# Docker-Compose build image from Git repo

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I should start by saying this I am aware that this project structure may not be ideal, but this is what the higher-ups want so I cannot change this.

I have multiple Java projects in one repo which I'd like to containerise into a single container:

```
- main
    - project1
    - project2
    - Dockerfile
```

I have no issue with that; my issue is that I need some other code from a (public) GitHub repo to be running in its own container, within my project container.

```
- main-container
    - project1
    - project2
    - git-repo-container
```

I can clone the repository and get it into the container with no issue (assuming `git` has been installed in a previous `RUN` command):

```
RUN git clone --progress --verbose https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Now, I'm completely stumped on how I go about building and running the container specified in the repo's `Dockerfile`.

Naturally, I turned to `docker-compose`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  my-image:
    build: .
    image: my-image
    ports:
      - 8080
      - 8100
  repo-image:
    build: .
    image: repo-image
    ports:
      - 8000
```

I'm new to `docker-compose` so this seems a little confusing to me but I am aware I can build images directly from GitHub. I'm just not sure how to specify the repo's `Dockerfile` given that I pull the repo in during the build phase (and would like to avoid installing docker in the container to run `docker build ...` in that container).

I should add that I cannot just add the repo's source code to this codebase (not my decision) so pulling in the repo during the build phase appears to be my only option.

As a bit of a side question, if permitted, is there a reason why VS code doesn't show the repo folder when I open the project in a dev container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker supports build from a direct github URL, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#git-repositories).

> docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

So, for you, after translate to compose, the correct way is next:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-image:
    build: .
    image: my-image
    ports:
      - 8080
      - 8100
  repo-image:
    build: https://github.com/user/repo.git
    image: repo-image
    ports:
      - 8000
```

Above will build an image based on third-party code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm getting somewhere but now it says `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: failed to load cache key: repository does not contain ref master, output: ""` is this because of the actual repo or I'm not doing something correctly?

Comment: It looks your git repo don't have master branch? You could refers to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#git-repositories to find a full usage: maybe `myrepo.git#mybranch`. If still issue, please show your git repo.

Comment: It's a newer repository, where they're renamed `master` to `main` but docker is telling me it cannot find the `master` branch, I'll try with `#main` on the end.

Comment: Update, it works with `#main` on the end so I guess that's the procedure to follow for repositories with a `main` branch instead of `master`, thanks for the help!

Comment: YEAH, looks Microsoft removes the old coding terms, but docker did not follow to set the default, glad to know that.